# div positions differs in chrome and firefox

Tags: html

i have a div

```
<div id="cpyright" class="copyright" >
</div>

.copyright {
    float: right;
    margin-right: -115px;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

this style gets gets applied in the firefox browser. but in chrome the div position is center. why is this happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `-115px`, `-20px` dirty positioning, how you want to exactly align your `div`? Right Left Center what?

Comment: I don't know how you get those numbers, but resetting the `margin` and `padding` of `body` smells good: `body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`.

Comment: i want the div to be positioned in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In must cases different positioning in different browsers are caused by the fact that each browser has some default CSS styles for elements. e.g margin for body. the best practice is to reset your CSS using one of the `CSS Reset` code template available (Google for it).

here is [an example by Eric](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/):

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0b1 | 201101 
   NOTE: WORK IN PROGRESS
   USE WITH CAUTION AND TEST WITH ABANDON */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

/* remember to define visible focus styles! 
:focus {
    outline: ?????;
} */

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

For your case you might want to position the div `absolute`ly in the `bottom right` corner. here is the right way to do it.

```
.copyright {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

Also you can use `position:fixed;` so even if user scrolls down the page, the `div` will remain at that fixed position.